# Counting values from inputs

Tags: javascript, html, input, html-table

I'm trying to sum the inputs in a table but I have a problem.
The table looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="ilosc" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="cena" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="ilosc" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="cena" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want to sum the first tr something like

ilosc * cena from first `tr` and from second same but I want to sum them something like

ilosc * cena + ilosc * cena

The main problem is this table is generated automatically so I can't add special id or classes.

Comment: Sounds like javascript and not java?? And how are you generating the table?

Comment: according to HTML tags and absence of javacode i think, that u chose bad section

Comment: You can't add special ids or class.. But, there must be some agreement like it will be the only table in the document and you always need the sum of all rows.. Please elaborate

Comment: @scrappedcola You said "Java is not identical to JavaScript." I think all you needed was != as "not equal" rather than !== as "not identical to".

Comment: @PiotrWrona Is a jQuery solution ok? Or you need pure js

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery allowed then you can do somethig like this

```
var arr=new Array();

$('tr').each(function(){
var $inputs=$(this).find('input');
var result=$inputs.first().val() * $inputs.last().val();
arr.push(result);
});

alert((arr[0]+arr[1]));
```

Or By this...

```
var ilosc=$(".ilosc");
var cena=$(".cena");
var result=0; 

ilosc.each(function(index, value){

           result=result+(($(value).val())*($(cena.get(index)).val()));
 });
alert(result);
```

You can se Demo at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Eafu/)